# Number of tasks while reading HDFS in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

[image]There are 200 files in a non formatted table in ORC format. Each file is around 170KB.The total size is around 33MB.

Wondering why the spark stage reading the table generating 7 tasks. The job is assigned one executor with 5 cores.

Comment: Task per partition.

Comment: But the question is why there are 7 partitions. My understanding was either it should have as many partitions as number of files or it should have partition per 128MB of data. Neither of these is the case here.

Comment: Show the spark ui.

Comment: @thebluephantom Added Spark UI in question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way Spark maps files to partitions is quite complex but there 2 main configuration options that influence the number of partitions created:

[`spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html) which is 128 MB by default and sets the maximum partition size for splittable sources. So if you have an 2 GB ORC file, you will end up with 16 partitions.

[`spark.sql.files.openCostInBytes`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html) which is 4 MB by default and is used as the cost to create a new partition which basically means that Spark will concatenate files into the same partitions if they are smaller that 4MB.
If you have lots of small splittable files, you will end up with partitions roughly 4MB in size by default, which is what happens in your case.

If you have non-splittable sources, such as gzipped files, they will always end up in a single partition, regardless of their size.