# Reading single parquet-partition with single file results in DataFrame with more partitions

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

**Context**

I have a `Parquet`-table stored in HDFS with two partitions, whereby each partition yields only one file.

```
parquet_table \
    | year=2020 \
        file_1.snappy.parquet
    | year=2021 \
        file_2.snappy.parquet
```

My plan is to only grap the latest partition and work on that.

```py
df = spark.read.parquet("hdfs_path_to_table/parquet_table/year=2021/")
```

This works, I only retrieve the required data.
While I wrote that for `pySpark` I assume that pure Spark will be somehow analog.

**Problem**

Despite the fact that I retrieve the correct data, Spark still has two partitions connected to the DataFrame `df`:

```py
df.rdd.getNumPartitions()
# -> 2
```

When I count the contents inside the partitions, I see that only one yields data:

```py
df.rdd.mapPartitions(lambda partition: [len([row for row in partition])]).collect()
# -> [1450220, 0]
```

Of course I can now easily do a `df.coalesce(1)` and end up with the desired result.
Anyhow, I wonder why this happens and I'd actually rather do not want to have to coalesce but directly only retrieve the partition.

**Question**

Is there any solution how my DataFrame `df` will only have the corresponding correct `.getNumPartitions()`?
Thus, is there a way to load a single `parquet`-file and yield this file in a single partition?

Comment: is your file size greater than `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes` ?

Comment: @mazaneicha: Yes it is. I'll check tomorrow if it makes an impact. Anyhow, I doubt it since the above example can be replicated (at least in my case) with a random number of partitions and the empty ones + full one will always be equal to the overall amount of partitions.

Comment: BTW: I checked your proposal but nothing changed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the issues is that `partition` is an overloaded term in Spark world and you're looking at 2 different kind of partitions:

- your dataset is organized as a `Hive-partitioned` table, where each partition is a separate directory named with <partition_attriute>=<partiton_value> that may contain many data files inside. This is only useful for dynamically pruning the set of input files to read and has no effect on the actual RDD processing
- when Spark loads your data and creates a DataFrame/RDD, this RDD is organized in splits that can be processed in parallel and that are also called partitions.

`df.rdd.getNumPartitions()` returns the number of splits in your data and that is completely unrelated to your input table partitioning. It's determined by a number of config options but is mostly driven by 3 factors:

- *computing parallelism*: `spark.default.parallelism` in particular is the reason why you have 2 partitions in your RDD even though you don't have enough data to fill the first
- *input size*: spark will try to not create partitions bigger than `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes` and thus may split a single multi-gigabyte parquet file into many partitions)
- *shuffling*: any operation that need to reorganize data for correct behavior (for example join or groupBy) will repartition your RDD with a new strategy and you will end up with many more partitions (governed by `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` and AQE settings)

On the whole, you want to preserve this behavior since it's necessary for Spark to process your data in parallel and achieve good performance.
When you use `df.coalesce(1)` you will coalesce your data into a single RDD partition but you will do your processing on a single core in which case simply doing your work in Pandas and/or Pyarrow would be much faster.

If what you want is to preserve the property on your output to have a single parquet file per Hive-partition attribute, you can use the following construct:

```py
# Read your partitioned dataset and filter on your preferred partition(s)
df = spark.read.parquet("hdfs_path_to_table/parquet_table/").filter("year = 2021")

# do your work
df_output = df.<do_something>

# repartition impacts how Spark organize the data in RDD splits
df_repartitioned = df_output.repartition("<partition attribute>")

# PartitionedBy impacts how Spark organizes data on disk in separate folders
df_repartitioned.write.mode("overwrite").partitionedBy("<partition_attribute>").parquet("hdfs_output")
```

If you process some of your partitions and don't want to overwrite the complete output every time, be sure to set `spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode=dynamic` to only overwrite the affected Hive partitions.

Comment: Your post is correct.  There is only subtly that also applies and (likely isn't related to this issue) is that if this hive-partition had multiple files, spark would use multiple splits/partitions despite your requested parallelism/shuffle partitions.  One split per file, that would eventually run into your parallelism/shuffle partitions at a later time and then follow your settings as required.  (Once you shuffle the daa it would obey your settings). It's a subtle point that may not apply here but worth adding to your answer for completeness.

Comment: In the general case, there is no one-to-one relationship between files and splits on input. Multiple files may aggregated into a single split if they are very small and a single large file may be broken down into several splits. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69034543/number-of-tasks-while-reading-hdfs-in-spark